# SSH ask for a password in VSCode Dev Container even if ssh-agent seems correctly configured?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, openssh, ssh-agent, vscode-devcontainer

I've configured Windows 11 ssh-agent following the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials#_using-ssh-keys) and then used `ssh-add` to add my SSH keys:

```
PS> Get-Service ssh-agent

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent
```

Command `ssh-add -l` show the key (just 1):

```
PS > ssh-add -l
3072 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Marco@PC-MARCO (RSA)
```

**I can successfully connect to a remote machine (i.e. `ssh user@remote.mydomain.com`) using the SSH key from the Windows machine**.

From the documentation:

> [...] the extension will automatically forward your local SSH agent if one is running

In fact inside a Visual Studio Code WSL2 container, the `ssh-add -`l command show the same output:

```
vscode ➜ /workspaces/test-ssh-agent $ ssh-add -l
3072 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Marco@PC-MARCO (RSA)
```

However inside the container the same exact command `ssh user@remote.mydomain.com` ask for a password.

It seems that it doesn't know that for that user/domain the stored SSH key should be used. Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT**: this is the debug log, it can't find the private key (of course) because inside the container. What's the point of ssh-agent then?

```
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/vscode/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this guide](https://snowdrift.tech/cli/ssh/git/tutorials/2019/01/31/using-ssh-agent-git-windows.html) and most importantly I updated OpenSSH to the latest version available here: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases

Now works without any problem.